# How to add selected checkbox in pref

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to add selected checkbox in pref and when user close the app,pref will clear,but when i open the app,i am getting all the checkbox selected and even pref is not working,following is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/

    private ListView lvData;
    private ArrayList<ModelUser> modelUsers;
    private ArrayList<ModelUser> modelUserArrayList;
    private ModelUser modelUser;
    private PrefsManager prefsManager;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String url="";
    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        lvData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvData);

        Loaddatas();


    }


    private void Loaddatas() {

        showpDialog();
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest( url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("ress", response.toString());


                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                String heder=obj.getString("filterName");

                                System.out.println("Hader"+heder);

                                JSONArray details=obj.getJSONArray("getParam");
                                modelUsers = new ArrayList<>();
                                modelUserArrayList =new ArrayList<ModelUser>();
                                for(int j=0;j<details.length();j++)
                                {

                                    JSONObject det=details.getJSONObject(j);
                                    modelUser = new ModelUser();

                                    modelUser.setUserName(det.getString("paramName"));
                                   // modelUser.setSelected(false);
                                   // modelUser.setId(i);

                                    modelUsers.add(modelUser);


                                }

                                mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,modelUsers);
                                lvData.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                prefsManager = new PrefsManager();

                                modelUserArrayList = prefsManager.getFavorites(MainActivity.this);
                                if(modelUserArrayList != null) {

                                    for (int k = 0; k < modelUserArrayList.size(); k++) {

                                        Log.e("User Name ",""+modelUserArrayList.get(k).getUserName());
                                       Log.e("User SElected ",""+modelUserArrayList.get(k).isSelected());
                                      //  Log.e("User user Id ",""+modelUserArrayList.get(j).getId());
                                    }
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }



                        hidepDialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("ErrorVolley", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();

            }
        });

        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(req, "jreq");
    }


    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: shared preference  not clear when application close its clear only  when you uninstall it or cleardata from setting  for that app.

Comment: ok but right now i am not able to store data

Comment: still you stuck there??

Comment: i followed this //http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/
but i am not able to do with json parsing

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper can you tell

Comment: why you use preference manger you have to  use shared preference see your in tutorial link saved favourite method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121505/discussion-between-rosy-and-android-developer).

Comment: get reference http://codetheory.in/android-application-data-storage-sharedpreferences/.

Comment: and this too.http://www.geeks.gallery/multiple-checkbox-values-in-listview-storing-retrieving-using-sharedpreferences/

Answer (score 1):

try this, for the pref part:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

//initialize
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
editor = pref.edit();

//get value
String var = pref.getString("any_tag_name", "default_return_value");

//put value
editor.putString("any_tag_name", "value");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: as you can see i tried with prefmanager,somehow i am able to manage that,but still one thing not able to do,can you help

Comment: right now i am able to store selected values in pref, and if i open again my app,selected values remain same as in pref,till here it works fine,now what i am trying is if user close the app and open it again,then selected values should be clear

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121505/discussion-between-rosy-and-android-developer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setPreference(String name, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putString(name, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

and use apply in place of commit, as the apply is faster

for getting it use

```
public static String getPreference(String name, String defaultValue) {
    return getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).getString(name, defaultValue);
}
```